# draw a graph dynamically in c# condition is that StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, lxml.html

```
    StringBuilder mStr = new StringBuilder();

    dtReports = GameLib.Reports.GetReportList();

    mStr.Append("<asp:Chart ID='Graph' >");
    mStr.Append("<Series>");

    mStr.Append(" </asp:Series>");
    mStr.Append("</Series>");
    mStr.Append("<ChartAreas>");
    mStr.Append("<asp:ChartArea Name='ChartArea1' BorderColor='64, 64, 64, 64' BackSecondaryColor='White'>");

    mStr.Append("<Area3DStyle Rotation='1' Perspective='10' Inclination='15' IsRightAngleAxes='False' WallWidth='0' Enable3D='false' IsClustered='False'>");
    mStr.Append("</Area3DStyle>");
    mStr.Append("<AxisY LineColor='64, 64, 64, 64' LabelAutoFitMinFontSize='5' TitleFont='Arial', 14pt, style='Bold'TitleForeColor='Black'>");
   mStr.Append("<LabelStyle Font='Arial', style='Bold' ForeColor='Black' />");
   mStr.Append("<MajorGrid LineColor='64, 64, 64, 64' />");
   mStr.Append("</AxisY>");
   mStr.Append("<AxisX LineColor='64, 64, 64, 64' LabelAutoFitMinFontSize='5'     Interval='Auto' TitleFont='Arial, 14pt, style=Bold' ,TitleForeColor='Black'>");

   mStr.Append(" <LabelStyle Font='Arial, 12pt, style=Bold', ForeColor='Black' >");
   mStr.Append("<MajorGrid LineColor='64, 64, 64, 64' />");
   mStr.Append("</AxisX>");
   mStr.Append("<%--<Position Height='75.02613' Width='90.26034' X='5.55474472' Y='14.414547' />--%>")
   mStr.Append(" </asp:ChartArea>");
   mStr.Append(" </ChartAreas>");
   mStr.Append("</asp:Chart>");
   mStr.Append("</div>");
```

This is code for graph to create dynamically,please help solve this error,some height and width detail deleted.please explain me how solve issue

Comment: Are you closing asp:Series without opening it? (</asp:Series>")

Comment: What error?  What is the actual resulting behavior of this and how does it differ from what you expect?  Also, it's *highly* irregular to use a `StringBuilder` to build server-side markup like this.  Is that markup even being processed before sending to the client?

Comment: It will not works as you expect, because it is just a string. In this case, you have to instance a `Chart` object and change properties of this object and after it, add on your page.

Comment: I just want to add the graph dynamically using string ,but its not coming as i expected.graph is exact similar as toolbox chart graph.

Comment: @user2783430: Define "its not coming as i expected."  What is the resulting output of this?  I'm *guessing* that you're just returning this server-side markup directly to the client, but I can't know that for certain unless you can confirm it in your output.  As I said, this is a highly irregular way of doing things.  You should have the markup exist on the page already and just dynamically show/hide it and dynamically set its properties, not try to dynamically add it entirely like this.

Comment: Actually, i have created a graph statically,but now another case is that, to create a 'n' number of graph in single div.Now i have to dynamically add the multiple graph as number of user increases. can you please tell me what is way to add same toolbox graph dynamically, Actually i have tried same method to create a table.its worked

Comment: @user2783430: You can instantiate a `Chart` object (or any `WebControl` object) in code and add it to something like a `PlaceHolder` control.  When you tried this method with a table, if it was just a normal HTML `table` then of course it worked, there's no server-side processing needed for plain HTML.  But for server-side controls, this method isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

OMG
Use control mate

```
var chart = new Chart();
var series = new Series();
series.XValueMember = "Age";
//and so on

//on the page
this.Controls.Add(chart);

//or if you want add it to panel
panel.Controls.Add(chart);`
```

or you can use your code but you need to build it dynamicly using CompilerService after that you should render it and after you have to set it in to some elements innerHtml and so on...